# R: Find X-value corresponding to specific Y-value on graph

Tags: r

I study a continuous variable, measured every ten minutes for 2 hours.
I wonder what at what time the variable has doubled and tripled.

```
Example data:
# The time variable
time <- seq(from = 0, to = 120, by=10)
# The measured variable
value <- c(5, 5.5, 7.8, 8.3, 9.5, 10.9, 11.5, 12, 13, 14, 12.5, 11.1, 9)
# Put together
df <- data.frame(time, value)
# Plotted
ggplot(df, aes(time, value)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

```
# At what time point (what X value) does Y equal (for example) 10?

# I've tried (according to previous suggestions on this site (but they turned out to be not reliable, and heavily dependent upon the "interval" specified.

f1 <- approxfun(df$time, df$value)
optimize(function(t0) abs(f1(t0) - 10), interval = c(0, 120))[[1]]
```

Does anyone know of any other function that can find the X value without dependence upon an interval. The reason for me asking again, is that changing the interval slightly (but keeping it within the true value) changes the result...

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is useful and practical for you, but my idea is to fit a (polynomial) curve to your data and then use this curve to "predict" (find) your x value for any y value. In case your y value corresponds to multiple x values you'll keep the first one.

I suggest you to run the process step by step to see how your initial dataset gets transformed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# The time variable
time <- seq(from = 0, to = 120, by=10)
# The measured variable
value <- c(5, 5.5, 7.8, 8.3, 9.5, 10.9, 11.5, 12, 13, 14, 12.5, 11.1, 9)
# Put together
df <- data.frame(time, value)

# Plot value (x axis) againt time (y axis)
ggplot(df, aes(time, value)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

You need a process that excludes the overlapping parts. I'm using a process that spots when the "value" value (x axis) starts getting smaller. Those cases are excluded.

```
# create a row index
df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) -> df

df_updated = 
    df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%          # for each row
    do(data.frame(.,max_value = max(df$value[df$id <= .$id]))) %>%   # obtain the maximum value up to that point
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(value >= max_value)     # exclude declining parts


# Plot value (x axis) againt time (y axis) from the updated dataset
ggplot(df_updated, aes(time, value)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Those are the data points you need to consider.

```
# filt a polynomial curve that best describes your data
fit <- lm(time~poly(value,8,raw=TRUE), data = df_updated)   ## NOTE that here it requires some extra work to find which degree gives you an acceptable fit (you can create a process that calculates your optimal degree. Here I used 8).

# check how good your fitting is
ggplot(df_updated, aes(time, value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(predict(fit, df_updated), value))
```

[image]

```
# get the time at value = 10
predict(fit, data.frame(value=10))

 #        1 
 # 41.67011
```

Comment: Many many thanks! I was, however, looking for a function that predict the X value at a certain Y value. If I've understood your function it does the opposite? I need to find the X value, for a certain Y. I appreciate Your time.

Comment: Sorry, I was carried away by the plot and the shape. I think the other way around is not possible using this approach as one value for y (eg. value = 10) will have to return 2 values for x (time).

Comment: Indeed I like Your approach to solve it with a prediction using polynomials, but it appears to be impossible, as you stated. This baffles me because it doesn't appear particularly difficult at first glance...

Comment: It's not difficult if you decide what to do with cases where a y value corresponds to multiple x values.

Comment: Based on the plot you provided it doesn't. Your y axis at value = 10 -for example- corresponds to 2 x axis values (time values). Do you need to keep only the first x value maybe? Depends on what your objective is.

Comment: My apologies for this; yes I'm not interested in the declining part of the graph... in other words, yes, only the first x value.

Comment: Ok, this seems easy in your example as there is one point that the graph starts declining, but if you have ups and downs you'll have a more complicated problem. I'll update my code soon.